# remove_action From PHP Class in WooCommerce Memberships

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I have previously used a solution described here: [remove_action From PHP Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431558/remove-action-from-php-class) for removing an action in the WooCommerce membership plugin.

However, the solution no longer works, as WooComemerce have changed the code behind the membership plugin.

So this is the new code.

**Main woocommerce-memberships.php**

```
public function includes() {

    // load post types
    require_once( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/includes/class-wc-memberships-post-types.php' );

    // load user messages helper
    require_once( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/includes/class-wc-memberships-user-messages.php' );

    // load helper functions
    require_once( $this->get_plugin_path() . '/includes/functions/wc-memberships-functions.php' );

    // init general classes
    $this->rules            = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-rules.php',            'WC_Memberships_Rules' );
    $this->plans            = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-membership-plans.php', 'WC_Memberships_Membership_Plans' );
    $this->emails           = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-emails.php',           'WC_Memberships_Emails' );
    $this->user_memberships = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-user-memberships.php', 'WC_Memberships_User_Memberships' );
    $this->capabilities     = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-capabilities.php',     'WC_Memberships_Capabilities' );
    $this->member_discounts = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-member-discounts.php', 'WC_Memberships_Member_Discounts' );
    $this->restrictions     = $this->load_class( '/includes/class-wc-memberships-restrictions.php',     'WC_Memberships_Restrictions' );
```

**Main instance**

```
    function wc_memberships() {
    return WC_Memberships::instance();
}
```

**From included class-wc-memberships-restrictions.php file**

```
    /**
 * Returns the general content restrictions handler.
 *
 * @since 1.9.0
 *
 * @return null|\WC_Memberships_Posts_Restrictions
 */
public function get_posts_restrictions_instance() {

    if ( ! $this->posts_restrictions instanceof WC_Memberships_Posts_Restrictions ) {
        $this->posts_restrictions = wc_memberships()->load_class( '/includes/frontend/class-wc-memberships-posts-restrictions.php', 'WC_Memberships_Posts_Restrictions' );
    }

    return $this->posts_restrictions;
}
```

**Then in class-wc-memberships-posts-restrictions.php**

```
    public function __construct() {

    // decide whether attempting to access restricted content has to be redirected
    add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'handle_restriction_modes' ) );

    // restrict the post by filtering the post object and replacing the content with a message and maybe excerpt
    add_action( 'the_post', array( $this, 'restrict_post' ), 0 );
```

How do i remove the 'the_post' action?

So far i have the following in functions.php theme file:

```
  function weteach_remove_actions(){
      if(is_singular( 'post' )) {
         if( function_exists( 'wc_memberships' ) ){
             remove_action( 'the_post', array( wc_memberships()->restrictions, 'restrict_post' ));
         }
      }
      return;
  }
  add_action( 'the_post', 'weteach_remove_actions', 1 );
```

Which gives me a "blank-page"-error.

Comment: Blank page means an error on your site, turn on WP_DEBUG in wp-config to see which error you get and fix that first.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the anwser. I just turned on WP_DEBUG, but is still getting a blank screen. I have also tried "add_action( 'wp', 'weteach_remove_actions', 1 );" instead og "add_action( 'the_post', 'weteach_remove_actions', 1 );"

Comment: Also try turning on `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to have the error logged to `wp-content/debug.log`. Though I think I figured out that this code was missing the `get_restrictions_instance()` in the main `woocommerce-memberships.php` file, so I was not accessing the `post_restrictions` correctly. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you tell us what the error message was? My guess is that `restrictions` and `post_restrictions` aren't the same property and so you aren't finding the `restrict_post` method in the right class.

**Edited** now that I have looked at Memberships, this seems to work for me:

```
function so_41431558_remove_membership_post_restrictions(){ 
    if( function_exists( 'wc_memberships' ) && version_compare( WC_Memberships::VERSION, '1.9.0', '>=' ) && is_singular( 'post' ) ){
        remove_action( 'the_post', array( wc_memberships()->get_restrictions_instance()->get_posts_restrictions_instance(), 'restrict_post' ), 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_41431558_remove_membership_post_restrictions', 1 );
```

Your `add_action` attempt is happening on priority 1, which is *after* the function has already run the Memberships method on priority 0, so even if the rest of your code was correct it would be too late.

So 1. I think we need to go to an earlier hook.

And 2. I think we need to use the new method for accessing the post restrictions class instance.

**edited to add**

and 3. I've switched to a direct version compare condition

and 4. I misread where the `get_posts_restrictions_instance()` method was... it is accessed via `wc_memberships()->get_restrictions_instance()->get_posts_restrictions_instance()`

Comment: Hi  helgatheviking,

Thank you so much! It works :-)

I did however need to add priority 1 to the add_action like this:

add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_41431558_remove_membership_post_restrictions', 1 );

for it to work.